# Updating 2 tables in one query when similar data does not exist in both

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update multiple tables in a single query, but what I using does not seem to do any updating.

```
UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.name='John Doe',table2.name='John Doe'
WHERE table1.id=1 and table2.id = 1;
```

Problem is, a row with the same id may not be present in both tables. How can I do an update in a case like this?

In this case, the `id 1` is present in table1, but not in table2.

**EDIT**
The idea is the update data in both tables, even if an id does not exist in table1 or table2

**Example:**

```
id is present in table1 but not in table2 -> Update table1. 

id is present in table2 but not table1 -> update table2. 

id is present in both table1 and table2 update both.

id is not present in either tables -> do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
UPDATE table1
       LEFT JOIN table2 
           ON table1.id = table2.id
SET    table1.name = 'John Doe',
       table2.name = 'John Doe'
WHERE  table1.id = 1
```

Comment: I tested this, but this still will not work if a row with id = 1 isn't present in both tables.

Comment: use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN works. I hope it's ok doing this and there won't be problems.

Comment: Ok. So this wont work if an Id were present in table2, but not table1. Any way of doing that? I tried full join, that wont work either.

Comment: The idea is to the update both the tables even if an id isn't present in both.

Comment: in your original query, try using `OR` eg `WHERE table1.id=1 OR table2.id = 1;`